# FCM Token not Unique

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

push notifications work well on my Android app but on my iOS app I keep getting error that FCM token is not unique

I am sending these parameters

```
{
    "identifier": "", 
    "name": "username", 
    "type": "ios", 
    "user": 68, 
    "registration_id": "cY4hE65tB2I:APA91bEa1B2l663d7pRtI-rfIBRXA8BRyI15mDX7TPg1LlE535WaSbNdkoer8FkOO8O_gBZ27M8do_usYuY4Acj6RJdj-K-t4tSCN16JIy3bcjH_CqbjJrteeqimXnf9wxepJnDg-2SC1", 
    "active": true
}
```

but getting error response

```
{
    "registration_id": [
        "This field must be unique."
    ]
}
```

Please advise, everything works great on Android but iOS has been a pain

Comment: Are the posted parameters the fields of `data` payload?  If so, you should not use `registration_id` as a key.  It is one of the [reserved keys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-plain-text).  The linked doc states: _The key should not be a reserved word ("from" or any word starting with "google" or "gcm"). Do not use any of the words defined in this table (such as collapse_key)._

Comment: ok so what should I be doing instead?

Comment: If `registration_id` is a key you have defined in the `data` payload, change your code to use some other name, like `reg_id`.

Comment: I am using registration_id on Android without issues and get notifications no problems, how can this be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not use this`registration_id` on another device before?